# Does this polynomial belong to this ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

We have the ideal $I = (X^2 + 1)$ of the polynomial ring $Q[X]$. We are asked to give an example of a polynomial that doesn't belong to the ideal $I$ and has $3$ non-null elements, and justify why it doesn't belong.

My example is: $f = X^2 + X + 1$

We assume that: $f = (X^2 + 1)g$, $g \in Q[X]$. So, $X^2 + X + 1 = (X^2 + 1)g$. If I evaluate this equation in $0$ then $1 = g$, but it doesn't show me anything, right? I can't evaluate this equation in $I$ since we are working with $Q$. Should I pick a specific $g$?

How can I prove $f$ doesn't belong to $I$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea that $f \notin (x^2+1) = I$ is correct. If $f \in (x^2+1)$, then $f(x)-(x^2+1) = x$ would also be in $I$.

But the degrees of non constant polynomials of $I$ are at least equal to $2$. A contradiction for $x$.

Therefore $f \notin I$.

Answer (score 3):

$X^2+X+1=g(X^2+1)$ implies that $deg(g(X^2+1))=deg(g)+deg(X^2+1)=deg(X^2+X+1)$, we deduce that $deg(g)=0$, $g$ is a constant and the coefficient of $X$  in $g(X^2+1)$ is zero contradiction.